# Disable keyboard controls for video player in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, video, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am using Flicker video player to play videos from network in flutter web. When I disable the controls and hide them, it's still working with keyboard shortcuts like m for mute unmute, left right keys for forward and backward. I want to disable these keyboard shortcuts as well. Anybody did this or know about this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flick Video Player](https://pub.dev/packages/flick_video_player) dependency documentation says;

> You can pass webKeyDownHandler argument to FlickVideoPlayer and manage the keyboard shortcuts yourself.

Maybe with this parameter you can pass null values to shortcuts and disable them. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this code and it works. Thanks to @Slender suggestion.

```
FlickVideoPlayer(
    flickManager: flickManager,
    webKeyDownHandler: (event, manager) {
        return null;
    },
)
```